# Parsing html-page with <br> tags

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

My app parses html-page like this:
    |html>
    |body>
    Text1 |br>
    Text2 |br>
    Text3 |br>
    |/body>
    |/html>

And me need display text successively, maintaining a line break.
All text is displayed solid line.
I tried to replace the 
 on <\n>, but it's not working.

Here is the text code:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;
        try {   
        doc = Jsoup.connect("ip").get();    
        title = doc.select("body");
        titleList.clear();      
        for (Element titles : title) {
        String item = titles.text();
        item = item.replaceAll("[<br />]", "\n");
        titleList.add(item);  
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
        return null;
        }
```

Can you prompt, how display text in keeping 
 newline?

Comment: Why do you have `<br />` enclosed in [] in your replace call? That isn't valid HTML, and should not be returned to you (so the call replaces nothing). And are you sure that there is a space in the `<br />` tag?

Comment: If not enclosed <br> in [], the condition fails and displays a continuous text. 
But with this condition all the symbols b and r are replaced. Is it possible to make the change only group of characters? And I use <br /> because it takes such a value variable. I checked through debug.

Comment: Just a little food for thought, if you're getting html, why not use a webview to display it, instead of formatting it to display it yourself?

Comment: But is it possible to implement it in ListView?

Comment: It should be... Can you make a list of all the Strings that you get from `titles.text()`?

Comment: All html-code: <html><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" type="text/css"> <title>Журнал web-сервера</title> </head> <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"> <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr style="height: 1px"> </tr> <tr style="height:29px"> <td></td> </tr> </table> 27.02.2014 | 12:31:29 | SetActive error: Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use. Web-server is not started<br>. And on the rest of the text with tags.

Comment: That's not what I meant, in your code, you grab all the elements in the body: `title = doc.select("body")`. From this you enumerate over all the child elements: `for (Element titles : title)` (though it would make more sense to name `title` `titles` and vice versa). For every element you call the `.text()` method. I am curious what the output is of these calls. Not just all the html that you receive.

Comment: Also, don't paste requested information in a comment if it is a lot of stuff. Just edit the question so you can format it.

Comment: I get all the text that comes after the closing table. Plus the title of the title. Before closing the body. Generally, I quote tag or class html-code and it displays all text me out of it, going through all the lines of code. I hope I answered the question? (My eng is not very good.)

Comment: No, it doesn't sadly. I specifically asked you to copy & paste the contents of the item String because according to the documentation ([link](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text())), the `.text()` method only returns the text of all combined children (thus without tags). This would explain why the `replaceAll()` function has no effect.

Comment: You say that the replacement comes after word processing and you should try this condition before?

Answer (score 1):

Try That:

```
 String item = titles.text();
    item = item.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
```

remove braces [].

Comment: Tried, but not working. New lines start tag is not in place, and in obscure places, crashing sentences and words.

Comment: <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" type="text/css">
<title>Журнал web-сервера</title>
</head>
<body
bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="height: 1px">
</tr>

<tr style="height:29px">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
27.02.2014 | 12:31:29 | SetActive error: Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use. Web-server is not started<br>

Comment: where is <br /> there?

Comment: you want to replace <\n> to <br />??

Comment: Yes. In the example, only one line of text. At the end of each line tag <br>. But android replaces each symbol b and r, and the tag itself does not see, it seems.

Comment: I tried so, but to not working. He replaces characters in the proposals, and does not replace tags.